# Maintain perfect circle with img-circle in Boostrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Okay, this seems to be an issue with so many potential solutions but none that will work for what I want to do. I always want to display perfect circles, even if the underlying image is not a perfect circle. But, I don't want to specify an image dimension by px because I want it to be responsive. It seems that no matter which solution I try, the circles always either become warped into ovals or the picture dimensions completely take over and make it gigantic.

HTML:

```
<div class='item-image'>
    <img class='img-circle img-responsive img-center' src='#' />
</div>
```

Goal:

Regardless of the image size (rectangles), I want the part of the image beneath the red circle to show through.

[image]

Comment: what is that box under the circle?, can you describe better what exactly do you want?

Comment: Sorry, that represents the image. I only want to show what's in the circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is per ***overlay***. And make the circle with CSS!

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="#" class="img-responsive">
    <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

`.wrapper` has `position: relative` and `.circle` has `position: absolute` and `border-radius: 100%`.

The wrapper has to be positioned with `inline-block`. Center the wrapper with `text-align: center`.

---

Center an absolute positioned element as follows:

```
.el {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -(height / 2)%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -(width / 2)%;
}
```

---

If you want the image inside the circle, make the circle bigger.

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ch5v98n7/4/)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="circle">
</div>
```

and use css for image in background:

```
.circle{
      border: 2px solid red;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      border-radius:100%;
      background-image: url('')
    }
```

check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/za0odubc/1/)